# Window not remaining in single workspace

Tags: xubuntu, android, desktop-environments, workspaces, emulation

I'm running Xubuntu and right now I have the issue of some of my windows following me around when I change from one workspace to another, I set them the a specific workspace and also set them to be "Only in this workspace". But still they move whenever I do, like if they were set to "Always in visible workspace", the number of windows doing this is also pretty random, sometimes all of them, other a few, one or none.

This only happens with the windows of the ADV "Android virtual device". Which are non re-sizable windows, could that be related to the issue?

Is there a way to have them stuck in one single workspace?
Regards Jose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open ***Settings*** and go to ***Window Manager Tweaks***. There you should see 6 tabs: Cycling, Focus, Accessibility, Workspaces, Placement, Compositor. Click on Cycling and un-check "*Cycle through windows on all workspaces*" if it's checked. Next go to the second tab Focus, you'll see 3 options for when a window raises itself (meaning the window wants focus), choose either "*Switch to window's workplace*" or "*Do nothing*". Finally go to the fourth tab Workspaces and un-check "*Use the mouse wheel on the desktop to switch workspaces*".